# Can a sum of Pauli matrices be a real value?

Tags: operators, notation

In the page 2 of [Quantum Annealing for Constrained Optimization](http://arxiv.org/abs/1508.04212), the authors introduced a constraint term under the Constrained quantum annealing (CQA) section. The ultimate goal is to work out a problem Hamiltonian for a quantum adiabatic algorithm. The constraint is defined as follows:

$$
C (\{\sigma^z_i\}) = c
$$

Here, $c$ is a real number.

I understand that there might be generic function which takes Pauli matrices as input and output real numbers. In the second column of the same page, the authors give an example of $C$.

$$
C (\{\sigma^z_i\}) = \sum^n_{i=1} \sigma^z_i =  c
$$

**My question:**

How can a sum of matrices be a real number? Shouldn't it be another matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When one writes $A=c$, where $A$ is an operator and $c$ is a number, it is implicit that the r.h.s. actually denotes $c$ times the identity.